# AWS + Cloudformation + Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, java-8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, tomcat8

When I do a create stack with the following cloudformation template using the input parameter EnvironmentType "dev", it creates the ebs application, creates the environment inside the application and deploys the sample-app.war file from the S3 bucket.

Then I am doing an update stack using the same template with an input parameter EnvironmentType "stage", this time it removes the existing dev environment and creates the stage environment inside the application.

I also tried to create stack again using the sample template entering sample application name created in the first step and this time it shows application already exist.

My requirement is to retain the dev environment and stage environment to get created inside the sample application using cloudformation.

Any suggestions, please..

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: 'Create an ElasticBeanstalk Application, Environment and deploy the war file from S3 bucket'

Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    ParameterGroups:
      -
        Label:
          default: 'EBS Application Configuration'
        Parameters:
          - ApplicationName
          - ApplicationDescription
          - ApplicationVersion
      -
        Label:
          default: 'EBS Environment Configuration'
        Parameters:
          - EnvironmentName
          - EnvironmentType
          - EnvironmentDescription
          - EnvironmentCName
          - MinInstances
          - MaxInstances

Mappings:
  PropertiesMap:
    IntanceType:
      dev: 'SingleInstance'
      qa: 'SingleInstance'
      stage: 'LoadBalanced'
      prod: 'LoadBalanced'

Parameters:
  ApplicationName:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Name of the ElasticBeanstalk Application'

  ApplicationDescription:
    Type: String
    Description: 'ElasticBeanstalk Application Description'

  ApplicationVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Application version description'

  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Name of the Environment'
    AllowedPattern: '^([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|-)+$'

  EnvironmentType:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Type of the Environment (dev, qa, stage, prod)'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'dev'
      - 'qa'
      - 'stage'
      - 'prod'

  EnvironmentCName:
    Type: String
    Description: 'CName Prefix for the ElasticBeanstalk environment'
    AllowedPattern: '^([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|-)+$'

  EnvironmentDescription:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Description of the ElasticBeanstalk environment'

  MinInstances:
    Type: Number
    Description: 'Minimum load balanced instances (Mandatory for stage/prod)'
    Default: 2
    MinValue: 2
    MaxValue: 10

  MaxInstances:
    Type: Number
    Description: 'Maximum load balanced instances (Mandatory for stage/prod)'
    Default: 2
    MinValue: 2
    MaxValue: 10

Conditions:
  IsStageOrProdEnvironment:
    !Or [!Equals [stage, !Ref EnvironmentType], !Equals [prod, !Ref EnvironmentType]]

Resources:
  EBSApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref ApplicationName
      Description: !Ref ApplicationDescription

  EBSApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion  
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref EBSApplication
      Description: !Ref ApplicationVersion

      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket: deployable
        S3Key: artifacts/sample-app.war

  EBSApplicationConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref EBSApplication
      Description: 'ElasticBeanstalk Configuration Template'
      SolutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v3.0.2 running Tomcat 8.5 Java 8'
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: EnvironmentType
          Value: !FindInMap [PropertiesMap, IntanceType, !Ref EnvironmentType]
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MinSize
          Value: !If [IsStageOrProdEnvironment, !Ref MinInstances, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MaxSize
          Value: !If [IsStageOrProdEnvironment, !Ref MaxInstances, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']

  EBSEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref EBSApplication
      CNAMEPrefix: !Ref EnvironmentCName
      Description: !Ref EnvironmentDescription
      EnvironmentName: !Ref EnvironmentName
      TemplateName: !Ref EBSApplicationConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel: !Ref EBSApplicationVersion

Outputs:
  ApplicationURL:
    Description: 'ElasticBeanstalk environment endpoint'
    Value: !Join 
      - ''
      - - 'http://'
        - !GetAtt EBSEnvironment.EndpointURL
```

Comment: Are you using aws cli for deployment? Can you show the command line?

Comment: No, I used aws console to run this template and passed input parameters in the console itself.

Comment: Did you check that your "dev" and "prod" stacks have different names?

Comment: Yes, I tried creating two stacks with different names for "dev" and "prod". Since the application is already created for the dev environment, it shows application already exists and rolling back the stack creation.

Comment: I also tried updating the stack my-project-dev, this time it creates the staging environment and removes the dev environment.